# AS3 accessing stage from class

Tags: class, flash, stage

Timeline code:

```
import as3.first;

first._this=this;

var str1:String='this is timeline';
```

Class code:

```
package as3 {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class first extends MovieClip {

public static var _this:Object;

trace(_this.str1);

}

}
```

Error message:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.

Trying to wrap my mind around how classes work. Need to access timeline functions and variables from class. What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in all what you are doing is somewhat weird. May be, you just want [a document class](http://www.kirupa.com/flash/document_class.htm) for your SWF root? You as well could [add a class to any movieclip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html) in your library: both ways grant you access to timeline.

```
package as3 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class first extends MovieClip 
    {
        public static var _this:Object;
        trace(_this.str1); // you may place code here... but consider this:
                           // this area is STATIC, the code here 
                           // executes only once when class gets initialized,
                           // so, this happens BEFORE you assign first._this=this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an app made entirely in Flash Pro without using classes, except one class called "AndroidLink" which is the part of android native extension (.swc included in .ane). I use it to send strings from as3 to native java code inside extension. Also I can receive strings from native code to as3, but only inside the AndroidLink class. When i receive something, i need to call one or another function in timeline which i don't know how to do. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Imagine this: when a user opens my app and taps "New game", my as3 sends command to native code to show the fullscreen ad. When a user closes the add, "onClose" is triggered and native code sends a string to as3. My AndroidLink class receives the string with a value "ad closed" and then it needs to call function "newGame()" which is in the timeline. Hence the question "how to access the timeline from a class".

Comment: I would dispatch an event from AndroidLink instance (or from the class, if it's static) upon receiving data from java. Then you can create a listener in timeline. To do so, you may follow one of the many tutorials on dispatching events in actionscript. Like this one for instance: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-events-basix--active-10018 Alternatively you can pass a callback from timeline to AndroidLink, so it will be able to, well, call you back. For this you need to know how to access AndroidLink from timeline code. The latter depends on how you library code is structured.

Comment: Thanks again! Dispatching an event looks easy, except it won't allow me to dispatchEvent() from static function. Trying to figure out a workaround all evening, no luck so far. Why classes have to be so hard? :(

Comment: Few more hours and still nothing. Just as I couldn't access the stage, I can't dispatch events from my AndroidLink class. I lack the understanding of classes too severely i guess.

Comment: Finally I did it. Not sure how, I think I instantiated the AndroidLink class and dispatched event through that instance. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. I wasn't sure how I could possibly help any further. :)